# Does Krishna Bhagavatam say that Brahmins in Kaliyuga would not follow their Varna-Dharma?

Tags: dharma, bhagavata-purana, kali-yuga, brahmins

The narrator says (in Tamil) that, according to Krishna Bhagavatam, "in Kaliyuga, Brahmins will have no defining characteristics except the yagnopaveetam"

Source

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDx7cQm4tiE

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam Mahā-Purāṇa does say that, as do almost all the Purāṇika texts.

> [ŚB 12.2.3](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%A8/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A8)
>
> The Evils of the Kaliyuga
>
> दाम्पत्येऽभिरुचिर्हेतुर्मायैव व्यावहारिके ।
>  स्त्रीत्वे पुंस्त्वे च
> हि रति**र्विप्रत्वे सूत्रमेव हि** ॥ ३ ॥
>
> > 3. Mutual liking (and the family pedigree, social status, etc.) will be the criterion of selecting a partner of life, in marriage ;
> >    cheating is the order of the day in business relations; satisfaction
> >    of the sensual pleasure is the only consideration of the masculine or
> >    feminine, and **worthiness and wearing of the sacred thread
> >    (*Yajñopavita*) (and not the pious behavior or Vedic or *Shastric*
> >    learning) is the outward index of the Brahminhood.**
>
> [English Translation](https://archive.org/details/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/page/n2155/mode/2up) by Motilal Banarsidass Publication.

> [Alternate English Translation](https://archive.org/details/bhagavatapuranagitapress_201907/page/n1535/mode/1up?view=theater) by Gita Press Gorakhpur
>
> > 3. (Personal) liking will be the deciding factor in making the choice of partner in life, and trickery alone will be the motivating forces
> >    in business dealing. Capability of affording the sexual delight will
> >    be the (only) criterion of the masculine or feminine excellence, **and
> >    the sacred thread will be the only mark of Brahminhood.**

<sup>Access the Sanskrit + Hindi Translation of the same verse by Gita Press Gorakhpur [from here](https://archive.org/details/shrimad-bhagawat-mahapuran-vol-2-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n915/mode/2up).</sup>